# Function not returning correct value for found_posts filter

Tags: filters

I am trying to return found_posts value minus the offset and I am not getting the expected pagination.

```
  function homepage_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {

    //Define our offset again...
    $offset = 3;

    //Ensure we're modifying the right query object...
    if( $query->is_home() ) {

        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;

    }

    return $found_posts;

  }
  add_filter( 'found_posts', 'homepage_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
```

When the function tries to subtract $offset from $found_posts, I **do not** get the correct pagination, however if I echo the value out before returning I get the correct value.

Also, if I substitute **$found_posts - $offset** with an int literal I **do** get correct pagination.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

**EDIT**
Removed the is_paged condition because that was removing pagination in the admin panel. This works that same without the bug.

Comment: Did you try to write as `return ($found_posts - $offset);` instead although it seems not necessary according to php.net? Or did you try to put the result into a varaible and return that variable? If the value is right, it should be the same.

Comment: You my also try to use [`gettype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to examine the type of variable? Just try to understand in different perspective.

Comment: $found_posts is a string and $offset is an integer, and yes, I tried the parenthesis, I tried casting, even though like you said, in PHP, a string minus an integer should automatically make it an integer.

Comment: For context, specifically, the total number of posts is **37** as of now with a post per page of **17**. I want to make pagination recognize only **34** to have the first pagination page have a limit of **17** and the subsequent pages have a limit of **20**, therefore have **2** pages recognized instead of **3**. The pagination only works correctly when I return an int literal of **34**. `$found_posts - $offset` doesn't work and neither does `$found_posts - 3`, but `$found_posts - 4` works, but this is an incorrect number to use.

Comment: Yes, php have auto type and most of the cases are correct but not all. Did you try intval() to force the type to be both integer? eg `intval( $found_posts ) - $offset' so that it should be same as the literal value you tried to put. Because different version and settings of the code will affect the php automatic type case.

Comment: Yes, I tried using `intval()` and even tried storing `intval($found_posts)` in a new variable and subtracting the offset from the new variable, but it still is not working.

Comment: I just notice that you are using pagination in homepage. The behaviour of pagination in static front is different to other templates. That's probably the reason that the paged variable is not working as expected. Did you try the same pagination in other templates than homepage? If it works, they it might the reason. I have encountered similar problem. You may refer [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264284/static-frontpage-pagination-custom-loop/264700) and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119183/problem-kriesi-pagination-doesnt-work-in-homepage).

Comment: I am using the blog page as my homepage, not a static front. I am also getting correct pagination when I assign an int literal to $found_posts so pagination clearly is working. The operation $found_posts - $offset also gives the correct integer, but then pagination is incorrect. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out the found_posts filter runs 3 times on the homepage and the third echo within the innermost element says $found_posts equals to **38** which is accounting for an unpublished post. I only noticed the first echo that was printing **37** at the top of the page. So if I set the $offset to 4 in the filter it works fine. Not sure if this will produce errors later on, but this answers the initial question.

Comment: I suggest you find out why it run duplicately and see where it run. Remove those unwanted filters is wise for long run to avoid unexpected results.