# Can't Add Pagination

Tags: pagination, previous-post-link, paginate-links

I can't add a pagination to divide my posts between pages and navigate between pages. 
Currently all 20 posts I have loads at once. I want to add a pagination to the bottom of my Page and view posts by 5.

I have a custom post type that I defined as Project. I have 2 pages. Homepage and Journal. Homepage features the feed of my Project post type and Journal features my regular blog posts. I want both of these pages to have pagination.

My current index.php which is my Homepage is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<div class="portfolioBlock">    
<?php 
         $args = array('post_type' => 'project','posts_per_page' => 20 );
         $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

         if( $loop->have_posts() ):
            while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();            
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
         endwhile;
         endif;
?>
</div>
```

My readings settings is as follows:
[image: Reading-Settings]

I am curious if this is caused because of my custom post types, would appreciate any help or lead to help me add a pagination to the page.

When i tried the Googled solution paginate_links I didn't get any links.
I also tried previous_posts_link() and that gives me the links and I can move between pages, but each page reloads the same 20 posts, without any diving it up.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For static page pagination is a little bit different because the global variable $post behave differently. You may refer [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119183/problem-kriesi-pagination-doesnt-work-in-homepage) and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264284/static-frontpage-pagination-custom-loop/264700) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only 5 posts you should set `posts_per_page` to 5.
And by setting `paged` parameter to any number you want, you can query posts in a specific page.
For example if you want to get posts 6 to 10 you should do:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'          => 2 
);
```